# Is there a way to use gatsby-awesome-pagination with dynamically filtered data?

Tags: reactjs, filter, pagination, gatsby

I am using gatsby-awesome-pagination. In my CMS (Contentful) I have a number of `Profile` data types each with `category` fields. I am creating a paginated listing for each category in gatsby-node.js like such:

```
// fetch data from CMS & create unfiltered paginated list
const directory = path.resolve('./src/templates/directory.js')
const profiles = result.data.allContentfulProfile.edges

awesomePagination.paginate({
  createPage,                // The Gatsby `createPage` function
  items: profiles,           // An array of objects
  itemsPerPage: 12,          // How many items you want per page
  pathPrefix: '/directory',  // Creates pages like `/blog`, `/blog/2`, etc
  component: directory,      // Just like `createPage()`
})

// create categorised directory pages 
const categories = result.data.allContentfulProfile.categories
categories.forEach((category) => {
  const categoryProfiles = profiles.filter(
    (profile) => profile.node.category === category
  )

  awesomePagination.paginate({
    createPage,
    items: categoryProfiles,
    itemsPerPage: 12,
    pathPrefix: `/directory/type/${slugify(category, {
      lower: true,
    })}`,
    component: directory,
    context: {
      category: slugify(category, { lower: true }),
    },
  })
})
```

Within `directory.js` itself, I am querying for data like this:

```
export const directoryQuery = graphql`
  query DirectoryQuery($limit: Int!, $skip: Int!) {
    paginatedProfiles: allContentfulProfile(
      sort: { fields: [createdAt], order: ASC }
      skip: $skip
      limit: $limit
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          // fields
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Up til this point I am basically just following the tutorial for gatsby-awesome-pagination and there is nothing surprising going on here. Now is where I combine this with a filter, which updates state with the `selectedCategory` via a simple `<select>`.

Then I go off-piste. I am preparing the data within `directory.js` by doing:

```
    const profiles = get(this, 'props.data.paginatedProfiles.edges')

    prepareIndexData(items, filterField, filterItem) {
        let sourceItems = null
    
        if (filterItem) {
          if (filterField === 'category') {
            sourceItems = items.filter(
              (item) =>
                slugify(item.node[`${slugify(filterField, { lower: true })}`], {
                  lower: true,
                }) === filterItem
            )
          }
        } else {
          sourceItems = items
        }
    
        return sourceItems
      }

And finally displaying the data on `directory.js` by doing:

    render() {
      return (
            <div width={12}>
              {this.prepareIndexData(profiles, 'category', category).map((profile) => (
                <ProfileCard key={profile.node.slug} profile={profile} />
              ))}
            </div>
      )
    }
```

This correctly filters by category on the Profiles, but only on those Profiles in the first 12 Profiles. This is because despite the fact I have built the page correctly in `gatsby-node.js` and passed `$skip` and `$limit` appropriately, I am still essentially querying on the original unfiltered paginated data in the form of `paginatedProfiles` in `directory.js`.

Is this the wrong way to go about this? Can this even be done on a static site or am I better off migrating to Next.js?

Answer (score 0):

> This is because despite the fact I have built the page correctly in
> `gatsby-node.js` and passed `$skip` and `$limit` appropriately, I am still > essentially querying on the original unfiltered paginated data in the form of > `paginatedProfiles` in `directory.js.`

You hit the nail. This is exactly what's happening

The way you are using `gatsby-node.js` is just to create dynamic pages from a CMS (Contentful) source, basically, without knowing what will be each category name. So, to achieve what you are trying to do, I think you just need to create a new [page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/) in your `directory.js`, without `$limit` and `$skip` filters, but filtering by category (to only get categories) and use that data as you are doing now. Something like:

```
 const profiles = get(this, 'props.data.yourNewQuery.edges')

    prepareIndexData(items, filterField, filterItem) {
        let sourceItems = null
    
        if (filterItem) {
          if (filterField === 'category') {
            sourceItems = items.filter(
              (item) =>
                slugify(item.node[`${slugify(filterField, { lower: true })}`], {
                  lower: true,
                }) === filterItem
            )
          }
        } else {
          sourceItems = items
        }
    
        return sourceItems
      }

And finally displaying the data on `directory.js` by doing:

    render() {
      return (
            <div width={12}>
              {this.prepareIndexData(profiles, 'category', category).map((profile) => (
                <ProfileCard key={profile.node.slug} profile={profile} />
              ))}
            </div>
      )
    }


export const directoryQuery = graphql`
  query DirectoryQuery($limit: Int!, $skip: Int!) {
    paginatedProfiles: allContentfulProfile(
      sort: { fields: [createdAt], order: ASC }
      skip: $skip
      limit: $limit
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          // fields
        }
      }
    }
   yourNewQuery: allContentfulProfile(filter: { contentType: { in: ["category"] } }){
      edges {
        node {
         // fields
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

*Note: change the `filter` to a new one that matches your use case.*

Comment: Thanks so much for the response @Ferran.

So in your solution with the updated query just to clarify, that wouldn't have any aspect of pagination? So If I selected 12 items per page, had 20 items in total, and then applied a category filter which matched 14 Profiles, then all 14 would show using your suggestion. Is there any way to get pagination & filtering together?